# Read csv table with blankvalue

Tags: java, bufferedreader, import-from-csv

I am using BufferedReader to read a CSV file. The csvfile I have is a table and does contains blank value so it prints out as ", ,". Instead of just printing blank I want to put in a "blankspace" so it prints out as ",blankspace,".

```
             try {
            BufferedReader brd = new BufferedReader(new 
            FileReader(DataFile));
            brd.readLine();
            while (brd.ready()) {


                String st = brd.readLine().trim();


                oneRow = st.split(",");

                Rs.add(oneRow); 

                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(oneRow));
            } 
        }
```

Comment: Without mention too much the fact that you should use API to read a CSV because it is much more complex than you think. Just check the content of each cell and change the value based on the condition ?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can replace before spliting; i.e.
instead of

```
oneRow = st.split(",");
```

you can do

```
oneRow = (st.startsWith(",")? "blankspace," + st.substring(1):st).replaceAll(",,", ",blankspace,").split(",");
```

Comment: Just added a check if the first cell is blank